# Matching a query distribution to a family of template distributions

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, bayesian, model-selection, matching

I was turning over a hypothetical question in my head: Suppose I have a set of template probability distributions, let's say each giving the probability of the occurrence of certain objects like cats,dogs, face, telephones etc. in a single class of image.

For e.g. distribution-1 is the probability of occurrence of these objects in a photo taken outdoors in winter. Distribution 2 is the probability of occurrence of these objects in a photo taken indoors at night. And similarly for any other classes of images we could imagine.

So my question is, suppose I have a query image which I believe belongs to one of these template classes. I can calculate by some means the probability distribution of objects on the query as well.

Then, what would be a principled way of choosing which template it belongs to? And then what would be the subsequent method to "clean" my noisy query distribution? In particular, is there a name for this class of problems, selecting a distribution from a set?

Thanks

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved and easier to follow if it employed standard capitalization and punctuation. Please consider an edit. (The more effort you put into constructing a well-defined and well-presented question, the more likely you will receive a response with the same qualities.) Cheers.

Comment: (+1) For the update.